# How to set an icon for an QML Plasmoid

Tags: qt, icons, qml, kde-plasma, plasmoid

I have a very simple Plasmoid (it consists of only 1 JS file and 1 main.qml file). I've been browsing the internet for almost an eternity, but I can't figure out, how to set an icon the for the plasmoid to use in the KDE panel.

Comment: Actually, you can add a plasmoid to the panel, or any other panel you've added to the desktop. Unfortunately, a lot of them don't have an icon specified for usage in panels. Also unfortunately, I don't know enough to figure out how to remedy this. It seems to be specified in one of more of the plasmoids files: metadata.json, metadata.desktop, config.qml

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In 5 minutes I found [a tutorial](https://techbase.kde.org/Development/Tutorials/Plasma5/QML2/GettingStarted) and a quick browse of the sources shows that you should add an "Icon" entry in your plasmoid metadata.desktop file.

See the Calculator applet as a simple example:
https://cgit.kde.org/kdeplasma-addons.git/tree/applets/calculator/package/metadata.desktop#n117

That icon should then translate into those SVG icons (per theme) you have in /usr/share/icons

Comment: Well, that doesn't set an icon for the KDE panel, that Icon is used in the "Add Widget" dialogue.

Comment: "Add widget" IS a panel. Please define "KDE panel", cause I'm not sure if what you're asking is even possible for a plasmoid.

Comment: What I mean by "panel" is the main application menu bar.

Comment: As far as I know, you cannot add a plasmoid to a panel. You can add applications, and for that there is another file. See Dolphin for example: https://github.com/KDE/dolphin/blob/master/src/org.kde.dolphin.desktop#L46

Comment: Using installed icons (like Icon=system-file-manager) works fine, even in the application menu bar, so maybe there is a problem with my custom icon. I'll try to find some information about icon formats.

Comment: It doesn't explain how to include a new icon, which would be the case for a plasmoid that isn't part of KDE